# UE4 Dedicated Server with critical error EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: unreal-engine4

I use UE4.26.2 and window10.
After i followed the [UE4 guide : Setting up Dedicated Servers](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/InteractiveExperiences/Networking/HowTo/DedicatedServers/), i can get folders and files that are packaged by UE4 engine. And i make shortcut `FPSServer.exe` with "-log" tag as well. But the problem is happened when i run it. Many text lines appeared and suddenly were closed before i check what logs on the Prompt. Fortunately, i can stop scrolling it clicking Mouse1 on Prompt screen.

```
=== Critical error: ===
Fatal error!

Unhandled Exception: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION reading address 0x0000000000000200

0x00007ff7685fc444 FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff76549663a FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff76549c9cb FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff765b3ac09 FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff765d85627 FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff76833ead5 FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff7647917d1 FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff768301f3e FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff7683207c2 FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff768d0bebc FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff768d12403 FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff76909a87d FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff7690b722f FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff7654efb4f FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff7654eff4e FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff765500e1b FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff7691056f2 FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff7691107d2 FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff7689d22ef FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff7689dbbd2 FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff76883b2fe FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff764652d9d FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff76466630d FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff7646663ca FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff764676630 FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff76a443fbe FPSServer.exe!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ffb8cc17034 KERNEL32.DLL!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ffb8ce82651 ntdll.dll!UnknownFunction []
```

It is only what i just have known about EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION is for Pointer problem. But i don't understand why my game is working well on UE4 editor with using multiplayer option and why this problem is appeared after package my game. Could you please help me to solve this error and let me know why it is happened?

Comment: It's not possible to say why it's happening just now. But you could try packaging with debug symbols - it's an option in project settings IIRC. That will name and shame the functions you've printed, from there you'll also be able to attach visual studio when it crashes to debug it properly.

Comment: @George Here is my [git link](github.com/kjinwoo12/UE4Study-NetworkFPS). I just try build as "DebugGame Server" and run it on visual studio debugger. And i can three Exception Thrown. `LaunchEngineLoop.cpp 607 line`: "UE4Server-Win64-DebugGame.exe has triggered a breakpoint", `OutputDevice.cpp 61 line`: "Exception thrown: read access violation. this was nullptr." and "Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation. this was nullptr." Even if i try to continue then it's looped at `OutputDevice.cpp 61 line` and it show me the same two message.

Comment: @George Did i do wrong? Actually i don't understand well. By the way, `And i can three Exception` -> `And i can see three Exception`. It's typo. My mistake